# React - antd modal above another modal

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have modal (B) that gets open above another modal (A).

When using z-index 1000 for A and 1001 for B, it's not always working and B can open behind A.
When using 100 and 101 it's always working.

I can't understand what is the reason for this difference.

I expected that use 1000 and 1001 will behave the same as 100 and 101.